# .dbproj VS 2005?

Tags: visual-studio-2005

I have Visual Studio 2005 Professional Edition and I am looking to build a solution which has a .dproj in it.

Does anyone know of VS 2005 Pro SP1 supports .dpproj files and if it does what do I need to fix it?

Error: ".dproj is not installed"

Cheers,
Conor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am pretty sure you need the `Visual Studio 2005 Team Edition for Database Professionals` SKU for that, see here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb310560(VS.80).aspx

Comment: Nasty, I had hoped there would be an easier way around this...
Thanks!
Conor